# Qual é a relatividade da unidade rem?

Tags: css3

Eu tenho a seguinte folha de estilo:

```
html{
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 40px;
    padding: 32px;
}
p{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding: 2rem;
    margin: 1.8rem;
}
```

Eu sei que a fonte dos meus parágrafos terá o tamanho de 24 pixels. Mas e quanto ao `padding` e ao `margin`?
E se eu usasse `rem` para definir por exemplo `line-height`, `height`, `max-width` e outros?

A que são relativos os diversos estilos medidos em `rem`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Citando a documentação do W3C sobre a unidade `rem`:

> #### rem unit
>
> Equal to the computed value of ‘font-size’ on the root element.
>
> When specified on the ‘font-size’ property of the root element, the ‘rem’ units refer to the property's *initial value*.
>
> #### unidade rem
>
> (É igual ao valor computado de 'font-size' no elemento raiz.
>
> Quando especificado na propriedade 'font-size' do elemento raiz, as unidades 'rem' referem ao *valor inicial* da propriedade.)

Sendo a tag `<html>` do documento o "elemento raiz" em questão, a unidade `rem` é relativa ao `font-size` computado para esse elemento.
Quando `rem` é usado para especificar o `font-size` do "elemento raiz", o `rem` é relativo ao valor inicial (ou valor padrão) de `font-size` especificado no W3C: `medium`.

> Eu sei que a fonte dos meus parágrafos terá o tamanho de 24 pixels. Mas e quanto ao padding e ao margin? E se eu usasse rem para definir por exemplo line-height, height, max-width e outros?

Qualquer propriedade calculada em `rem` recebe o tamanho computado do `font-size`, logo, se o `font-size` do elemento raiz for de `16px`, `1rem` representará `16px`.

```
html {
    font-size: 16px;   /* 1rem = 16px */
    margin: 40px;
    padding: 32px;
}
p {
    font-size: 1.5rem; /* 1.5rem * 16px = 24px   */
    padding: 2rem;     /* 2rem   * 16px = 32px   */
    margin: 1.8rem;    /* 1.8rem * 16px = 28.8px */
}
```

Fontes:
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#font-relative-lengths
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#propdef-font-size
http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/font-size

Comment: Mais sucinta do que a outra resposta, mas não contém a principal resposta. E quanto à outras propriedades? Quanto à `font-size` eu já sei. Como diz na pergunta.

Comment: `rem` é uma unidade de medida relativa ao tamanho do `font-size`, então as outras propriedades que recebem, digamos 1rem, recebem 1 vez o tamanho do `font-size` do elemento padrão. Se o `font-size` do elemento raiz fosse 16px, então 1rem = 16px, logo, `padding`, `line-height` e outras propriedades ficariam com 16px.

Comment: Então ponha isso no corpo da resposta. =]

Comment: Agora ficou bonito!

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

Unidades REM são relativas ao tamanho definido no elemento principal e não relativas ao elemento-pai do seletor onde `font-size`tenha sido definido.

---

## O que são REM e EM em CSS?

### *EM*

O “*em* é uma unidade escalável usada em mídia Web. O valor *em* é baseado na largura da letra M maiúscula. Este valor será igual ao `font-size` definido na página ou o padrão do navegador (provavelmente 16px) caso este não tenha sido definido em lugar algum.

Exemplo #1:

```
body { font-size:62.5%; }
h1 { font-size: 2.4em; } /* =24px */
p  { font-size: 1.4em; } /* =14px */
```

Se o valor padrão do navegador para `font-size` é de 16px, 62.5% disso são 10px, então 1em equivale a 10px. E por ser uma unidade escalável, 2.4em é 2.4x 10px (24px), bem como 1.4em é 14px.

Um dos problemas de se usar **em** com tamanhos de fonte é seu efeito cascata, que força o desenvolvedor a ficar pra sempre definindo regras nos seletores filhos para resetá-los de volta a 1em.

Além disso, o dimensionamento de fontes com **em** é composto. Uma lista dentro de uma lista não tem 14px e sim 20px<sup>[contexto requerido]</sup>. Adentre mais um nível e a fonte passa a medir 27px.

Exemplo #2

```
<style>
    body  { font-size: 100%; }
    p, li { font-size: 0.75em; }
</style>

<p> 12px text </p>

<ul>
    <li> 12px text
        <ul>
            <li> 9px text </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```css
body  { font-size: 100%; }
p, li { font-size: 0.75em; }
```

```html
 
    <p> 12px text </p>
    
    <ul>
        <li> 12px text
            <ul>
                <li> 9px text </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Esses problemas podem ser contornados declarando em qualquer elemento filho que este use 1em, evitando o efeito cascata indesejado.

CSS3 agora tem o **rem** que previne esse comportamento.

### *REM*

REM é um acrônimo para *Root EM*. Unidades REM permitem a você definir um valor principal no elemento HTML e então usar nos elementos subseqüentes valores relativos à essa unidade principal.

A unidade *rem* também é escalável, mas em relação a elementos específicos na página, sem afetar os outros elementos

Exemplos:

```
 html { font-size: 62.5%; } 
 body { font-size: 1.4rem; } /* =14px */
 h1   { font-size: 2.4rem; } /* =24px */
```

Todos os browsers recentes suportam unidades *REM*. Para browsers que não a suporta temos que usar como *fallback* opção em pixels (px):

```
 html { font-size: 62.5%; } 
 body { font-size: 14px; font-size: 1.4rem; } /* =14px */
 h1   { font-size: 24px; font-size: 2.4rem; } /* =24px */
```

No segundo exemplo (com HTML) alterar a definição para:

```
p, li
{
  font-size: 12px;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}
```

Garante que os elementos <li&gt: filhos permaneçam com 12px.

```css
body  { font-size: 100%; }
p, li { font-size: 0.75rem; }
```

```html
 
    <p> 12px text </p>
    
    <ul>
        <li> 12px text
            <ul>
                <li> 12px text </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Um [terceiro exemplo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Eaxoav), um pouco diferenciado e mais estendido, envolvendo *paddings*.

No primeiro grupo de DIVs aninhadas, os valores computados são:

1. 20px
2. 48px
3. 72px
4. 108px

A primeira DIV recebe o valor global de 20px para todas as DIVs (20px). Sem um valor global, a DIV não tem *padding* (veja o console populado pelo JS anexo ao *snippet*).

Da segunda em diante os valores passam a ser **2em**, ou 2x, o valor computado do elemento anterior, respeitando-se o *box-model*:

1. 20px
2. 48px = 20px + 4px (borda) x 2
3. 72px = 20px + 4px (borda) + 48px (elemento-pai)
4. 108px = 20px + 4px (borda) + 72px (elemento-pai)

Isso demonstra bem o efeito cascata cumulativa que eu disse.

No segundo grupo de DIVs aninhadas, a primeira reporta os mesmos **20px** global e todas os *paddings* computados das DIVs aninhadas reportam **32px**.

**Mas por quê se o *padding* do *root em* já é de 32px e o "global" é de 20px?**

Porque... é relativo... ao `font-size`. Experimenta trocar o *padding* do seletor HTML para qualquer valor e vai ver que, com exceção do próprio seletor HTML, claro, todas as DIVs aninhadas continuam a reportar os mesmos **32px**.

Agora mudamos o valor do `font-size` , digamos... **20px**, por exemplo.

A primeira DIV continua reportando os **20px** globais e todas as demais DIVs reportam **40px**, ou seja, **2em**, ou 2x, os **20px** definidos no `font-size`.

Fonte #1: [CSS-Stars](http://css-stars.com/rem-and-em-in-css/)

Fonte #2: [SitePoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/new-css3-relative-font-size/)

Comment: Não responde realmente à pergunta.

Comment: Como não? Além de responder a pergunta explica o porquê disso acontecer além de exemplificar a diferença deom REM em relação ao EM.

Comment: O foco da pergunta é definir outras propriedades com `rem` e não o `font-size`. Não falei sobre `em`.

Comment: Você não entendeu. REM é a unidade de medida de um valor mensurável. Eu exemplifiquei com `font-size` porque fica mais evidente. Pode até ser que quando aplicado à outras propriedades tenham-se comportamentos diferentes, mas se você esperava outro tipo de resposta, então explique melhor sua dúvida.

Comment: Está bem explicada. Ali pergunta especificamente sobre outras propriedades. Eu até citei que eu já conheço o efeito no `font-size`.

Comment: Adicionei mais um exemplo envolvendo *paddings*. Espero que agora atenda suas expectiativas.